# ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 1

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, pylance

I am writing this ML model for identifying diabetes risk factors in a population by collecting data from research publications on Google Scholar and deducing from those related to the subject matter of diabetes in africa.

```
# Step 2: Data preprocessing
# Convert the text data into a bag-of-words representation
 vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
 X = vectorizer.fit_transform(articles)


# Apply term frequency-inverse document frequency (tf-idf) weighting
 transformer = TfidfTransformer()
 X = transformer.fit_transform(X)


# Define the target variable y
 relevant_keywords = ["diabetes", "risk factors", "Africa"]


# Define the target variable y
 y = []


# Loop through each article and check if it contains any relevant keywords
 for article in articles:
    relevant = any(keyword in article.lower() for keyword in relevant_keywords)
    y.append(int(relevant))
```

I really am stuck beacause at this point i have not found any info on stake overflow that has been helpful. I am newbie so anyone with experience should hep a brother out.
I have tried defining the classes to be best of my knowledge but it doesnt seem to work.

```
# Step 3: Feature selection
# Use chi-squared test to select the top 100 most informative features
 selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k=100)
 X = selector.fit_transform(X, y)


# Step 4: Model training
# Split the data into training and testing sets
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


# Train a logistic regression model
 clf = LogisticRegression()
 clf.fit(X_train, y_train) #[****This is the line that keeps bringing the error****]
```

This is the error response:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/iamobedson/Desktop/Projects/ML Model for Diabetes.py", line 57, in 
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py", line 1241, in fit
raise ValueError(
ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 1

Comment: Did you actually check that your y contains different values? And not the same value?

Comment: Yes I have, it's supposed to contain different values

Comment: Do not suppose, the error is literally telling you that your assumption is plain wrong.